# Async / Await on React not working. Nothing works

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, axios

Well, saying that everything else was tested and is working fine, I made this `PublicRoute` that sends a request to `NodeJS`, but the function `isAuthenticated` never awaits the response from back-end and always returns a `promise` instead of `true` or `false`. I searched everywhere on internet but did not find a solution. I don't know how to make it await.

**PublicRoute file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../context/auth';
import api from '../services/api'; // Axios.

function PublicRoute( { component: Component, ...rest } ) {
    const { authTokens } = useAuth();

    async function isAuthenticated ( token ) {
        if ( token === undefined ) return false;

        const data = {
            token
        };

        try {
            const response = await api.post( '/cT', data );
            if ( response.status === 200 ) {
                console.log( 'Retorned true.' );
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log( 'Retorned false.' );
                return false;
            }

        } catch ( error ) {
            console.log( 'Retorned false with error.' );
            console.log( error );
            return false;
        };
    }

    const estaAutenticado = isAuthenticated( authTokens );

    console.log( 'Is authenticated?' );
    console.log( estaAutenticado ); // It was supposed to return true or false, but always returns a promise.

    return (
        <Route { ...rest }
            render={
                ( props ) => ( estaAutenticado === true ) ?
                    ( <Redirect to='/profile' /> ) :
                    ( <Component { ...props } /> )

            }
        />
    );
}

export default PublicRoute;
```

**This is my Routes file:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { AuthContext } from './context/auth';

// Pages:

import PublicRoute from './pages/PublicRoute';
import PrivateRoute from './pages/PrivateRoute';
import Admin from './pages/Admin';
import Logon from './pages/Logon';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import User from './pages/Register/User';
import Ong from './pages/Register/Ong';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';
import NewIncident from './pages/NewIncident';


export default function Routes( props ) {
    const localStorageToken = localStorage.getItem( 'token' );

    let existingTokens = undefined;
    if ( localStorageToken !== 'undefined' ) {
        existingTokens = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'token' ) );
    }

    const [ authTokens, setAuthTokens ] = useState( existingTokens );

    const setTokens = ( token ) => {
        localStorage.setItem( 'token', JSON.stringify( token ) );
        setAuthTokens( token );
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authTokens, setAuthTokens: setTokens }}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <PublicRoute exact path='/' component={ Logon } />

                    <PublicRoute exact path='/register' component={ Register } />

                    <PublicRoute exact path='/register/ong' component={ Ong } />

                    <PublicRoute exact path='/register/user' component={ User } />


                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/administration' component={ Admin } />

                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/profile' component={ Profile } />

                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/incidents/new' component={ NewIncident } />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

Comment: It returns a promise because it's marked `async`, you need to `await` or `.then()` on the promise to be able to do anything with the result.

Comment: I already have tried to do:
const estaAutenticado = isAuthenticated( authTokens ).then( result => { return result; } );
It keeps returning a promise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isAuthenticated` is an async function, so you'd have to await the result before you can use it. But it's more complicated than that. Your `PublicRoute` function is a *component*, and components must synchronously return the content you want to render (at least until we get suspense). Since `isAuthenticated` is async, that means you have to render twice: once while the result of `isAuthenticated` is being determined, then again after. The easiest way to do that is with using state:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function PublicRoute( { component: Component, ...rest } ) {
    const { authTokens } = useAuth();
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        isAuthenticated(authTokens).then(setIsAuthenticated);

        async function isAuthenticated(token) {
            if ( token === undefined ) return false;

            try {
                const response = await api.post( '/cT', { token } );
                return response.status === 200;
            } catch ( error ) {
                console.log( 'Retorned false with error.' );
                console.log( error );
                return false;
            };
        }
    }, [authTokens]);

    console.log( 'Is authenticated?' );
    console.log( isAuthenticated ); // Will be null (unknown), true, or false

    if (isAuthenticated === null) {
        // Render nothing for now; component will re-render after auth check
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <Route { ...rest }
            render={
                ( props ) => ( isAuthenticated ) ?
                    ( <Redirect to='/profile' /> ) :
                    ( <Component { ...props } /> )

            }
        />
    );
}
```

Your component now returns content that React can handle instead of a Promise, and it handles the asynchronicity through re-renders. Your next focus should be "what should users see while they're waiting?" The approach this takes is to return `null` so the route isn't exposed, but you may want to consider rendering spinners which might require this auth check function being moved somewhere else in your component tree.

Comment: I think this is really the right path, but it only `console.log( isAuthenticated );` as `null` twice.

Comment: That doesn't make sense... is your `setIsAuthenticated` being called? Might need to add some logging to find out why that's not getting called.

Comment: It wasn't working because the `return response` in NodeJS was inside the token verification function. Holy moly!

Answer (score 0):

`async` is always paired with `await` keyword:

```
 const estaAutenticado = await isAuthenticated( authTokens );
                         ^^^^^
```

Now you can access the value in `estaAutenticado`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, because it means that I should make the route async (`async function PublicRoute ...`), and when I do it, I always receive from React: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: If that wasn't you meant, what is it then?